# How to pass file names to a subroutine in perl?

Tags: perl, file, io, subroutine

I'm writing a perl script and I would like to pass a file name for the output file to a subroutine.

I tried something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

test("Output.dat");

sub test {
  my $name = @_;

  open(B, ">$name") or die "Failure \n";

  print B "This is a test! \n";
  close(B); 
}
```

I'm going to use the subroutine multiple times, so i have to pass the file name and cannot declare it within the subroutine.

I hope you can help me :)

Comment: You have to assign input variables in list context (note the parens) `my ($name) = @_;` Also check http://perlmaven.com/scalar-and-list-context-in-perl

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
my $name = @_;
```

You are assigning an array to a scalar variable. In Perl this will give you the number of elements in the array - so I expect you're ending up with "1" in `$name`.

There are a number of ways to get the first element from an array;

```
my $name = $_[0]; # Explicitly get the first element
my $name = shift @_; # Get the first element (and remove it from the array)
my $name = shift; # Same as the previous example - shift works on @_ by default in a subroutine
my ($name) = @_; # The parentheses make it into a list assignment
```

The last two are the ones that you will see most commonly.

A few more points:

1/ You would get a better clue to the problem if you included `$name` in your error message.

```
open(A, ">$name") or die "Failure: $name \n";
```

Or, even better, the error message that Perl gets from your operating system.

```
open(A, ">$name") or die "Could not open $name: $!\n";
```

(I've added back the missing comma - I assume that was a typo.)

2/ This days, it is generally accepted as good practice to use the three-arg version of `open` and lexical filehandles.

```
open(my $output_fh, '>', $name) or die "Failure: $name \n";
```

3/ In your example you open a filehandle called "A", but then try to write to a filehandle called "B". Is this a typo?

Comment: Thank you! This helped!
Yes, you're right. I made some typos with the "A" and "B" as filehandle :)

Comment: concerning `1/`: ...and an even *better clue* if you include `$!` as well

Comment: @Wolf: I think I was editing my answer to add that at pretty much the same time as you suggested it :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
my $name = @_;
```

Will assign to `$name` value of `@_` in scalar mode. It means number of elements in array `_`. It is a number of arguments. It is most probably not what you would like. So you have to assign an array to an array or a scalar to a scalar. You have two options

```
my $name = $_[0];
```

or

```
my ($name) = @_; # or even (my $name) = @_;
```

Where I would prefer later because it can be easily modified to `my ($a, $b, $c) = @_;` and it is Perl idiom.

But your code has more flaws. For example, you should use this `open` form

```
open my $fd, '>', $name or die "cannot open > $name: $!";
```

This has few advantages. The first, you use lexical scoped IO handle which prevents leaking outside of the lexical scope and is automatically closed when exits this lexical scope. The second, list form prevents interpretation of `$name` content other than file name.

So resulting code should look like:

```
sub test {
    my ($name) = @_;

    open my $fd, '>', $name
        or die "cannot open > $name: $!";

    print $fd "This is a test!\n";
}
```

Comment: Good to have the 3-argument version of `open` shown here and the error code in `$!`. BTW: What is the advantage not using parenthesis with `open`?

Comment: Well :-) ...wouldn't it be good to include the OPs `close` in the *resulting code* snippet, or is there an automatism for this with `my` variables?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't read careful, you already wrote: *lexical scoped IO handle which prevents leaking outside of the lexical scope and is automatically closed when exits this lexical scope* - now I got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your question, would like to suggest one thing -

Always use 3 parameter open() version like -

```
open (my $FH, '>', 'file.txt') or die "Cannot open the file:$!";
```

If you are passing single parameter to the subroutine, you can use 'shift' operator.

```
test("Output.dat");

sub test {
    my $name = shift;

    open (my $B, '>', $name) or die "Cannot open the file:$!";
    print $B "This is a test! \n";

    close($B); 
}
```